# show last item of the gridview by default

Tags: android, position, selection, android-gridview

I want to show last item of the gridview by default, in case there are a no. of items in the gridview.

I tried the gridview property setSelection, but that is not helping me out.

Please direct me.

Comment: setSelection(int position) works for me but you need to call this method after setting the adapter and not before setting the adapter on the grid view.